# How to do C stdio.h read() in Python

Tags: python

I have a proprietary program which can execute a user provided program as a sub-process. The parent process writes some useful data to file descriptor number 4.

In a C program, the data in the file descriptor can be read using:

`s_count = read(4, &string_var[0], 100);`

I am trying to accomplish the same using Python.

The following does not work and hangs at the read.

```
stream = os.fdopen(4, "r")
stream.read()
```

Same problem with

```
os.read(4, 100)
```

I even tried changing the file descriptor to non-blocking.

Is there any way to just do what the `C` `stdio.h` `read()` does in Python ?

==============================================

Edit - ***SOLVED***:

The program had another writable stream on a different file descriptor.
The problem was solved after changing the input stream unbuffered i.e. the it was open passing `0` as the third argument to `os.fdopen`

Comment: refer [files](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/files.html?highlight=files) topic in python documentation.

Comment: BTW, the standard `open` function will accept a file descriptor instead of a filename, assuming the file descriptor is valid.

Answer (score 0):

in python open() returns a file descriptor, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).

```
>>> f = open('workfile', 'r+')
>>> f.write('0123456789abcdef')
>>> f.seek(5)      # Go to the 6th byte in the file
>>> f.read(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do make it non-blocking and then use select-poll.

```
fcntl.fcntl(4, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
poller = select.poll()
poller.register(o, select.POLLIN)
if poller.poll():
    print(o.read())
```